# Vue-cli3 vue-cli-service build --modern doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

After `npm run build --modern` runs successfully, I only see one app in the output. Shouldn't there be two? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After `npm run build --modern` runs successfully, I only see one app in the output. Shouldn't there be two?

Actually, the `build --modern` command creates two apps in `dist/js` (see `dist/js/app.4e3aeb0e.js` and `dist/js/app-legacy.10b7d753.js`):

```
➜ ls -al dist/js
total 1840
drwxr-xr-x  10 tony  staff     320 Sep  2 19:25 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 tony  staff     224 Sep  2 19:25 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff    4772 Sep  2 19:25 app-legacy.10b7d753.js                    <-- LEGACY
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff   23682 Sep  2 19:25 app-legacy.10b7d753.js.map
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff    4718 Sep  2 19:25 app.4e3aeb0e.js                           <-- MODERN
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff   23625 Sep  2 19:25 app.4e3aeb0e.js.map
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff   80454 Sep  2 19:25 chunk-vendors-legacy.df5f2e07.js          <-- LEGACY
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff  397535 Sep  2 19:25 chunk-vendors-legacy.df5f2e07.js.map
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff   63276 Sep  2 19:25 chunk-vendors.4fd390fb.js                 <-- MODERN
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff  326296 Sep  2 19:25 chunk-vendors.4fd390fb.js.map
```

The apps are selectively loaded in `index.html`. First, the modern-mode scripts are preloaded with [`<link rel="modulepreload">`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/modulepreload#so_is_link_relmodulepreload_just_link_relpreload_for_modules) in the `<head>`:

```
<link href=/js/app.4e3aeb0e.js rel=modulepreload as=script>
<link href=/js/chunk-vendors.4fd390fb.js rel=modulepreload as=script>
```

Those scripts are later loaded in the `<body>` (*Note: Only browsers that support `<script type="module">` would load the script*):

```
<script type=module src=/js/chunk-vendors.4fd390fb.js></script>
<script type=module src=/js/app.4e3aeb0e.js></script>
```

Finally, there's a [`nomodule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-nomodule) fallback to the legacy-mode scripts (*Note: The `nomodule` attribute tells the browser to load the script only if module scripts are not supported*):

```
<script>!function () { var e = document, t = e.createElement("script"); if (!("noModule" in t) && "onbeforeload" in t) { var n = !1; e.addEventListener("beforeload", function (e) { if (e.target === t) n = !0; else if (!e.target.hasAttribute("nomodule") || !n) return; e.preventDefault() }, !0), t.type = "module", t.src = ".", e.head.appendChild(t), t.remove() } }();</script>
<script src=/js/chunk-vendors-legacy.df5f2e07.js nomodule></script>
<script src=/js/app-legacy.10b7d753.js nomodule></script>
```

> I compare the size between the --modern and no modern, there is not difference?

I'm not sure how you're comparing the sizes, but the modern build is in fact larger in size. In the following example, I built a Vue-CLI generated app (with `default` preset) twice (once without `--modern` and again with `--modern`), and renamed the output directories. See the size increase in `dist-modern` of `index.html` and `js/`:

```
➜ ls -al dist*
dist-default:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   7 tony  staff   224 Sep  2 19:25 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 tony  staff   416 Sep  2 19:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 tony  staff    96 Sep  2 19:25 css
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff  1150 Sep  2 19:25 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x   3 tony  staff    96 Sep  2 19:25 img
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff   724 Sep  2 19:25 index.html
drwxr-xr-x   6 tony  staff   192 Sep  2 19:25 js

dist-modern:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   7 tony  staff   224 Sep  2 19:25 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 tony  staff   416 Sep  2 19:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 tony  staff    96 Sep  2 19:25 css
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff  1150 Sep  2 19:25 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x   3 tony  staff    96 Sep  2 19:25 img
-rw-r--r--   1 tony  staff  1213 Sep  2 19:25 index.html        <-- LARGER
drwxr-xr-x  10 tony  staff   320 Sep  2 19:25 js                <-- LARGER
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am new in the Vue.
Do I need to make some settings? I compare the size in this way too. There is not difference. And I try other options too like the `--report`. I don't find the report.html. So I guess I didn't make some settings. I read the docs, and there aren't something about the settings.

Comment: No settings are needed. What version of vue-cli are you using? I recommend installing the latest version (currently 3.0.1). Then, generate a project with the `default` preset, run `npm run build`, rename `dist` to `dist-1`, run `npm run build --modern`, and then compare the new `dist` directory with `dist-1`.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find the docs you put in the image, but from [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build) it says:

> `--modern` builds your app using Modern Mode, shipping native ES2015 code to modern browsers that support it, with auto fallback to a legacy bundle.

Then I'd interpret that as just one flexible app.

From the docs you mentioned at the comment, I found this relevant part:

> The cool part though is that there are no special deployment requirements. The generated HTML file automatically employs the techniques discussed in Phillip Walton's excellent post:
>
> **The modern bundle** is loaded with `<script type="module">`, **in browsers that support it**; they are also preloaded using `<link rel="modulepreload">` instead.
>
> **The legacy bundle** is loaded with `<script nomodule>`, **which is ignored by browsers that support ES modules**.
>
> A fix for `<script nomodule>` in Safari 10 is also automatically injected.

With that I'm able to interpret the same way, one app that behaves differently according to the browser.

Talking about the size, I'm not sure if it's necessary more settings to enable that, but according to the docs, it's not. I encourage you to continue reading them, for me this is the best way to be up to date to any needs.

Comment: the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#modern-mode) is here. And I compare the size between the --modern and no modern, there is not difference? Does it need other settings? I am new in the Vue.Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I try other options, they also don't work. Though I don't need the feature temporarily, I am still finding the reasons.